# Style a cascade list into table

Tags: css, list, css-tables

Just asking if there is a way to style a cascade list like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>col 1 row 1</li>
            <li>column 2 row 1</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>column 1 row 2</li>
            <li>col 2 row 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

into a table like this

```
------------------------------------------------------
|col 1 row 1               |column 2 row 1           |
|column 1 row 2            |col 2 row 2              |
------------------------------------------------------
```

where each row is a horizontal list with the same width

I've been experimenting to achieve this, but can only get as close as this

```
------------------------------------------------------
|col 1 row 1 |column 2 row 1                         |
|column 1 row 2 |col 2 row 2                         |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't make each cell the same width.
Here is my css

```
ol.question_list {
    list-style: decimal;
    width: 100%;
}

ol.question_list li {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.choice_list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.choice_list li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

and here is my sample html

```
<ol class="question_list">
    <li>
        <ul class="choice_list">
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>defghi</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="choice_list">
            <li>abc12345</li>
            <li>defghi12345</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

I've found the solution, but before I would like to thank for the response in this thread.
The solution is like this:

```
ol.row_list {
    list-style: decimal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

ol.row_list li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    line-height: 1px;
    font-size: 1px;
    clear: both;
}

ul.col_list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.col_list li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 8%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    display: table;
}
```

and the html looks like this

```
<div>
    <ol class="row_list">
        <li>
            <ul class="col_list">
                <li>abc
                </li>
                <li>12345
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="col_list">
                <li>abc12345
                </li>
                <li>1234567890
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the display: inline is killing you.  Otherwise, set a width for the "ol li ul li"s, and it should Just Work.  Perhaps a float on the second li would help, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.question_list {
    min-height: 10px; //clear float
}


.question_list li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

you try this?

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
ol,ul,li{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.question_list {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.choice_list li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<ol class="question_list">
    <li>
        <ul class="choice_list">
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>defghi</li>
            <br style="clear:both;" />
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="choice_list">
            <li>abc12345</li>
            <li>defghi12345</li>
            <br style="clear:both;" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```